# Tcolorbox that shrinks to content, but still provides text wrapping

Tags: tcolorbox

I have a box, myBox, that can either shrink to the content, or make sure to do wrap the contents inside the page boundaries. Is there a way do do both at the same time?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myBox}{
enhanced,
colback=black!20,
left=15pt,
right=15pt,
top=15pt,
bottom=15pt,
capture=hbox %  <--- This line
}

\newcommand{\myBoxWrapper}[1]{
\begin{center}
  \begin{myBox}
    \Large #1
  \end{myBox}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
  \myBoxWrapper{A short box}
  \myBoxWrapper{This is a long sentence that's so long that it will have to get a new line or else the printer is gonna print past the paper and all over my floor}
\end{document}
```

produces this. The upper box is right, the bottom one is wrong.

[image: Picture 1]

while

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myBox}{
enhanced,
colback=black!20,
left=15pt,
right=15pt,
top=15pt,
bottom=15pt,
capture=minipage %  <--- This line
}

\newcommand{\myBoxWrapper}[1]{
\begin{center}
  \begin{myBox}
    \Large #1
  \end{myBox}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
  \myBoxWrapper{A short box}
  \myBoxWrapper{This is a long sentence that's so long that it will have to get a new line or else the printer is gonna print past the paper and all over my floor}
\end{document}
```

produces this. The upper box is wrong, the bottom one is right.

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the option you're looking for is `tcbox width=auto limited` ([`tcolorbox` manual, p. 100](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page.100)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myBox}{
tcbox width=auto limited,
capture=hbox
}

\newcommand{\myBoxWrapper}[1]{
\begin{center}
    \begin{myBox}
        \Large #1
    \end{myBox}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\myBoxWrapper{A short box}
\myBoxWrapper{This is a long sentence that's so long that it will have to get a new line or else the printer is gonna print past the paper and all over my floor}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]